# Media file metadata editor for OS X

Tags: osx, video, music, id3, metadata

In order of priority, I am looking for a piece of software that:

1. Is not iTunes.
2. Will allow me to manually edit/create Apple-compatible metadata for audio (MP3, M4A) and/or video (MP4) files.
3. Has a clean and simple user interface. (I do not want a full-blown media organizer. A graphical interface is ideal.)
4. Is compatible with OS X El Capitan.
5. Is available as a precompiled binary.
6. Supports some form of batch processing. (Let me add properties to multiple files at once.)

---

The closest thing I've found is this [unofficial port of EasyTag](http://marcoschuh.de/wp/?page_id=411) to OS X, but the [download link is broken](http://marcoschuh.de/wp/static/d.php?file=EasyTAG_alpha5.dmg), and my efforts to contact the author have turned up in vain. A [different port](https://rfw.name/easytag-mac/) works great for MP3s (of which I have very few), but does not appear to work with any M4A or MP4 files, despite what its description claims.

Surely there's a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta seems to be the best option. It has all the features you wanted. It is a paid app, but there is a 3-day trial.

https://www.nightbirdsevolve.com/meta/

Comment: This is a super nice program for audio; however, it doesn't work on video at all. If it was free, it would be a great partial solution, but as a paid application... I don't know. I'm going to wait a few days and see if anyone knows of something better before committing money.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy Really? It worked with MP4 files when I tried it.

Comment: On a second try--it seems to work on anything smaller than 4 GB. So, it's the same problem EasyTag had, except it stops you beforehand instead of corrupting your movies! Must have something to do with 64 bit. This actually isn't too bad, as about half my movies are smaller than 4 GB.

Comment: Just wanted to check in—I downloaded an update for Meta today and Lo and Behold, it now supports files larger than 4GB! I now finally have a perfect metadata editor!

Answer (score 2):

So, it's been a couple of days, and I've managed to make some progress on my own. This is very, VERY far from a perfect solution, so I'd still really appreciate a more comprehensive recommendation.

First of all: After a LONG period of some quite intensive Googling, I finally found a working download link to the first of the two Mac ports of EasyTag. I would share this link directly, but as of today I can no longer find it in my history. As a result, I've uploaded the program itself to Amazon Cloud Drive [here](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/tZBhEDSWqVARBommyBqgy0JYXL6ODZCv1X81UikI7EN?ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy). If the author of the program has any issue with my re-hosting of his work, he should get into contact with me; as it stands, I have done my best to contact him and received no response.

This version of the program works on mp3, m4a and mp4 files. However, attempting to use it to modify the metadata on a file larger than 4 GB results in the file being corrupted. Yes, this means that if you do not have a backup, the file will be permanently destroyed!

Furthermore, the ability to select and change the properties of multiple files at once is completely broken in this version. There is an option at the top of the GUI to select multiple files, but only the first file is actually modified, leading me to conclude that this is a bug rather than an unimplemented feature.

The *other* Mac port of EasyTag (which I linked to in my initial question) is able to modify multiple files at once, but as stated in my initial post, it only works on mp3s. (I don't have any mp3's larger than 4 GB for obvious reasons, so I have not tested whether this functionality is present)

The other program which I've found is mp4box. Despite being a command line utility, it is able to modify the metadata on even very large m4a and mp4 files, and BECAUSE it's a command line utility, it's easy enough to construct a for loop that will let you modify multiple files at once. However, as you might expect from a program called mp4box, it doesn't work on mp3 files--and trying to do so anyway will leave you with corrupted data, which, again, means that you'd better have a backup in case you make a mistake.

---

So to conclude, we have:

1) EasyTag Port 1: Modify metadata on mp3, m4a, and mp4 files smaller than 4 GB. Does NOT allow batch processing.

2) EasyTag Port 2: Batch processing on mp3 files. Does NOT work on mp4 or m4a files.

3) Mp4box: Batch processing of m4a and mp4 files of any size, including those greater than 4 GB. Does NOT work on mp3 files and does NOT have a GUI.

Used together, these three programs support all of my use cases. What I cannot find, however, is a single, stable, and reliable solution.

Comment: Some months late to this, but you can install EasyTAG via Homebrew on macOS: http://brewformulas.org/EasyTag

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it just came up while I was searching to see what else is out there... I have used kit3 (https://kid3.sourceforge.io/) to edit metadata in mp3's, and it says it can do the following formats:

> Edit tags in MP3, Ogg/Vorbis, DSF, FLAC, MPC, MP4/AAC, MP2, Opus,
>   Speex, TrueAudio, WavPack, WMA, WAV, AIFF files and tracker modules
>   (MOD, S3M, IT, XM)

Comment: Just tried this in 2021 — works great on AAC files! (Still on MacOS 10.14.6 Mojave).

Answer (score 0):

I use Musicbrainz Picard. A slight threshold to get started (so does maybe not meet your third requirement, but that is subjective) but very competent. And it is free.